# Scrapy Not Producing Output CSV file

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Python 2.7 32 bit.  I downloaded and installed Scrapy 0.16.4.  I'm using Windows 7.  I installed it from this page http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/intro/install.html.

When I use cmd and type scrapy version it shows the program is installed.  When I attempt to run a spider from any tutorial it pulls the information from the page and displays it in cmd, but won't produce the output in a csv file and says that it didn't scrape or crawl any pages.

I'm confused because it seems to have installed properly and seems to be partially working...but it has the above stated problems.

I'm curious to know if anyone else has experienced a similar situation?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify better what commands you are issuing?

Comment: Please post your spider and item code along with the command that was run and the debug output.

Comment: I'll post them asap.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am afraid you don't run cmd as administrator. please upload the code to make the question less poor

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow this tutorial

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/intro/tutorial.html

Then run the scrapy using this

`scrapy crawl dmoz`

You can also get the ready made scrapy crawler from here to play with with

`https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot`

If you give us more info then we will give you more direction